# How to parse "Prince Andrew shook his head, laughing as a man laughs?"

Tags: commas, present-participles

"Prince Andrew shook his head, laughing as a man laughs." I guess it might be a participle clause about two actions happen at the same time in the past. So it could be "Prince Andrew shook his head when he laughed as a man laughs" but why there is comma before "laughing"?

As I saw on the grammar website, the comma should be placed if the sentence is like "emerging from the cocoon, moth swings the wings" (it's my one example). But if you wanna leave out the comma, then sentence should be like "moth swings the wings emerging from the cocoon", shouldn't it?

Comment: The word should be **head**, not **hand**., [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&ie=UTF-8&source=android-browser&q=Prince+Andrew+shook+his+hand%2C+laughing+as+a+man+laughs.&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: This is a duplicate of another question you asked, which is the better question, since it contains the entire sentence

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *laughing as a man laughs* modifies *Prince Andrew.* It means that while Prince Andrew shook his head, he laughed (in the manner typical of a man).

The word *laughing* functions as a present participle (not a gerund), even though it's describing something that happened in the past. Since the main verb, *shook,* is in the past tense, the "present" of the present participle is also in the past.

The comma is needed because *laughing as a man laughs* is a non-restrictive clause. It claims something about Prince Andrew beyond what the main clause, *shook his head,* claims. The need for the comma is more obvious if you reword the sentence like this:

> Prince Andrew, laughing as a man laughs, shook his head.

(This version of the sentence has clumsy rhythm, but that's even harder to explain than grammar!)